# Retrieve Last days data from TIMESTAMP(6) Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle TIMESTAMP(6) column (11g) that I'm trying to use in various queries to get the last day, last hour...etc data.  When I run the below it returns all the data.  I would expect it to not return any data as  the data_initiated column should not be greater than the current system time.

select * from table_name where date_initiated > SYSTIMESTAMP order by date_initiated desc

**returns:**

```
2014-04-09 18:35:55.414000
2014-04-09 18:20:30.020000
2014-04-09 18:19:29.052000
2014-04-09 18:19:03.461000
2014-04-09 18:12:25.231000
2014-04-09 17:40:57.262000
2014-04-09 17:10:47.058000
2014-04-09 16:12:57.509000
2014-04-09 16:09:28.769000
2014-04-09 16:08:02.386000
2014-04-09 15:20:48.896000
2014-04-09 14:32:10.713000
```

SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

**returns :**

```
04-09-2014 18:45:49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine this should work--minus however many days you want to look back:

```
select * from table_name where TRUNC(date_initiated) = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
```